# capistrano suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby, vagrant, capistrano

i'm using a ubuntu vagrant box with installed capistrano to develop an application.
when i tried to deploy i get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require': no such file to load -- capistrano/ext/multistage (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from ./config/deploy.rb:3:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from Capfile:4:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /usr/bin/cap:4
```

as google suggested i tried to reinstall capistrano, but this failed because of dependencies(net-ssh requires ruby >= 2.0)
so i installed net-ssh v2.9.2

```
sudo gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.2
Fetching: net-ssh-2.9.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed net-ssh-2.9.2
1 gem installed
```

but now the next dependency error occures...
How do i make a fresh installation of capistrano working?
do i need a newer version of ruby(apt-get install ruby tells me that the newest version is already installed)?
Or is the cause of this error something complete different?

Comment: From what I know you also need the "capistrano-ext" gem. But I guess you found that on ruby as well. My guess if capistrano was peviously working but now has conflicts with your ruby version, is that indeed you either need a newer ruby version, or, possibly easier install an older capistrano version. Do you know by chance which version you've been running before?

Comment: According to a short research, this should work:

gem install net-ssh -v 2.6.5
gem install capistrano -v 2.13.5

If not I would be curious what the next dependency error is.

Comment: the next error is:  highline requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
 and the old capistrano version should be: 2.15.5(defined in the vagrantfile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything in your trace about what version of ruby you're on, but you did say "net-ssh requires ruby >= 2.0", so you might need a newer version of ruby like you said. You can check the version of ruby you're using with `ruby -v`. I would also recommend using a version manager so that you can use multiple versions between projects. I find [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to be good starting points.

Comment: my ruby version is: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux] and according to apt-get this is the newest version available(on ubuntu 12), cant i just install the old version of capistrano(with the old versions of all dependencies) or do i have to upgrade ruby from a different source(not ubuntu official)?

Comment: Just a general note: ruby 1.8.7 is very old and unsupported. In general it's recommendable to use a ruby version manager like rvm or rbenv. Even if you do not require more then one ruby versions installed on the same machine this makes installing different ruby-versions much more convenient.  If you don't want to use a version manager, you will need to find the packages from an unofficial source I guess.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is strange...

after running vagrant provision multiple(~5) times and installing/deinstalling multiple gems and ruby versions the next "vagrant provision" fixed the problem magicaly. i still dont know why this error occured and what fixed it, bull i'll close this question...